# How does C# do runtime generics?

Tags: c#, java, generics, runtime

One thing that irritates me about Java is the awful implementation of compile-time translation of generic type arguments.

I can observe and understand that the C# implementation is far better, but I'm confused as to how it works.

Essentially, how can you say:

```
T t = new T()
```

If you don't know the type of T and therefore don't know the constructor argument requirements?

I can see

```
Class<T> cl = T.class
```

or

```
T[] tarr = new T[0]
```

but I don't see how you can really create a new instance of T if you don't know the requirements of constructing it?

Comment: I find it incredible that you treat `T t = new T()` as a desirable feature. It seems to me that it's a recipe for unmaintainable code.

Comment: It isn't, so long as you go the C# route and constrain T to have a certain type of constructor.  Read the answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only do `new T();` if T is constrained to have a plain, parameterless public constructor, for instance:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : new() {
    private myT = new T();
}
```

Additionally, there is no way to specify that any other sort of constructor exist.  This is not possible:

```
// Doesn't work
public class Foo<T> where T : new(String, Int) {
    private myT = new T("Foo", 5);
}
```

To your other points, this is how you get the type of T at runtime:

```
var tType = typeof(T);
```

and creating an array of `T` doesn't actually create any instances (unless `T` is a value type, in which case it creates the default value of that type):

```
// Space for 32 T's, but nothing in the array.
// If T is a value type, like an int for instance, 
// each one would have the default value (0 for int, for example)
var arrayOfT = new T[32];
```

Comment: Right.  I was just pointing out from a Java developer's perspective what made sense and what didn't.  So basically you can constrain T to be where a certain construction type is required.  That makes sense.  Why didn't Sun do that?

Comment: Probably because Java implements generics using type erasure.  At runtime, Java treats all generic parameters as `Object`, and so it doesn't have the information necessary to construct a `T`.  In .NET, the type of `T` is known at runtime, and so creating an instance is fairly trivial.

Comment: Frankly, C# learned from a lot of Java's mistakes.  Java wanted to make as few changes to the JVM as possible, so they used type erasure (where `T` becomes `Object`)...which takes less change to the JVM, but at the same time keeps it from knowing the real type of stuff.

Comment: See Sun designed the Java generics so that they wouldn't have to change the .class file format.  But they ended up having to do that anyway and didn't go back to redesign generics.  So now we are stuck with good for nothing generics where everything is assumed to be a constrained superclass or just Object.

Comment: @cHao you're right and generics aren't the only feature implemented as a compiler extension. I do not really disagree with this choice (thinking JVM as a cross-compiler environment). Moreover I think the compiler could do all the stuff whichever is the way the implemented generics so I can't understand why we have such poor support.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you ask the compiler to force `T` to have a parameterless constructor so he knows you can `new T()`. For example:

```
class Test<T>
{
    T Create()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

It won't compile because the compiler can't be sure that `T` won't be an abstract class and that it'll have a default constructor. To make it works you have to add a constrain on the real type of T:

```
class Test<T> where T : new()
```

Now the compiler will force `T` to be a non abstract class with a default constructor. For example this code is not valid because the given type is abstract:

```
abstract class AnotherTest
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Test<Derived> test = new Test<Derived>();
    }
}
```

Again, if you try to use a class without default constructor the compiler will emit an error:

```
class AnotherTest
{
    public AnotherTest(string someParameter)
    {
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Test<Derived> test = new Test<Derived>();
    }
}
```

With an array it's a little bit different. Actually you simply ask the compiler to reserve the memory for a given number of slots, you do not allocate the memory for that objects (in case of reference types it'll simply put `null` in each slot).

**References on MSDN**

- [Introduction to generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx)
- [Generic type constrain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)
- [The `new` constrain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot say `new T()` unless you constrain your generic type to have a parameterless constructor using the `where T : new()` constraint — see [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

And there are no “constructor argument requirements”, since the only supported constructor is the parameterless one. You cannot use, say, `new T(false)` — constraints of the form `where T : new(bool)` are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

`new T()` is just a syntactical sugar for `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`

Comment: Yes and no.  The former will only compile if `T` is constrained to have a public parameterless constructor.  The latter will compile regardless of whether or not `T` has such a constraint, but will fail at runtime if the type of `T` lacks a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: @supercat: Apparently `CreateInstance<T>` has a constraint `where T : new()`.  Considering you have the type at compile time, looks like it'd fail the check then and there.  We may be confusing `CreateInstance<T>` with `CreateInstance(Type)` here.

Comment: @cHao: It doesn't seem to have such a constraint.  A call to e.g. `Activator.CreateInstance<WaitHandle>`, definitely using the generic form, will compile just fine, but throw `MissingMethodException` when executed.  Note that allowing such code to compile is useful, since it allows for cases where code might want to handle different types differently, and would only need to actually call the default constructor for types which support one.

Comment: @supercat: Ahh.  Yeah, misread a bit.  :P  The example shows a constraint, but the method documentation itself doesn't.  Still, seems rather useless, considering the type needs to be known at compile time.  What does it get you over `new T()`?

Comment: @cHao: As a simple example, one might have a sparse-array collection class which needs to be able to populate elements with non-null instances; one constructor should accept a factory-method delegate.  It would be convenient to also have a constructor overload which did not require the delegate, but could simply use `new()`.  There's no way, however, to limit the compile-time use of such an overload to types which support `new()`.